# Pymongo and Atlas server selection timeout can't connect both with tls or not (now even mongodb js npm package)

Tags: python, mongodb, logging, pymongo

I've installed pymongo using `python3 -m pip install pymongo[srv]`.

I'm trying to connecting to my atlas database using the following python3 code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging
import pymongo

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

try:
  client = pymongo.MongoClient(f"mongodb+srv://admin:admin@cluster0.ut26d.mongodb.net/tgdrafts?retryWrites=true&w=majority"))
  logger.info(client.list_database_names())
except Exception as ex:
  logger.error("*** ERROR ***")
  logger.error(ex)
```

But I get always those errors:

```
2022-06-22 18:02:17,111 - __main__ - ERROR - *** ERROR ***
2022-06-22 18:02:17,111 - __main__ - ERROR - cluster0-shard-00-00.ut26d.mongodb.net:27017: timed out,cluster0-shard-00-02.ut26d.mongodb.net:27017: timed out,cluster0-shard-00-01.ut26d.mongodb.net:27017: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 62b33ceb768c55b1eef979a0, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-00.ut26d.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('cluster0-shard-00-00.ut26d.mongodb.net:27017: timed out')>, <ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-01.ut26d.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('cluster0-shard-00-01.ut26d.mongodb.net:27017: timed out')>, <ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-02.ut26d.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('cluster0-shard-00-02.ut26d.mongodb.net:27017: timed out')>]>
```

I can't figure out where I'm wrong...

In mongo db atlas I've opened the access from everywhere and my username and password have simple chars that doesn't needs to be parsed. I've tried both tls or not accesses.

Update: Even with this simple js script it doesn't work (from [official doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/tutorial/connect-to-your-cluster/#connect-to-your-atlas-cluster):

```js
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

const url = "mongodb+srv://admin:admin@cluster0.ut26d.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majori>
const client = new MongoClient(url);

async function run() {
    try {
        await client.connect();
        console.log("Connected");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.stack);
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
}

run().catch(console.dir);
```

Print only those errors:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/ap/Documents/deleteme/deleteme_mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:306:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

Comment: Are you using the [Atlas provided connection string](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/tutorial/connect-to-your-cluster/#connect-to-your-atlas-cluster "Link to MongoDB/Atlas tutorial -->")?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I've followed that guide for both python and node tutorials, both crashed. I've updated my question with js example.

Comment: Does this succeed (replacing username and password, ofc), `client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://admin:admin@cluster0.ut26d.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority")`?